# Per-vertex reflection and intersection calculation, OpenCL vs GLSL

Tags: opengl, reflection, glsl, intersection

I have to calculate the visibility field of a mirror on a plane (i.e: the floor).

The mirror surface is composed of several triangles (up to fewer thousands).

[image]

Each vertex define a mirror point, each mirror point may correspond to up 6 triangle vertices and has a normal.

In order to do this I should calculate the line between a specific point, representing the driver head (where all the blue lines come from), and each of the mirror points lying on the mirror surface (in the image on the right side). Then for each of these points, I should calculate their reflections (yellow lines) based on the direction of the i-th blue line and the i-th normal and therefore the intersection between the i-th yellow line and the floor.
Obviously both blue and yellow lines need to be tested for any intersection with the vehicle geometry during the process..

[image]

Right now the whole process is run on the cpu, with some approximations in order to make it faster, the original idea was then to move the calculation part on OpenCL..

I came from a Cuda environment (and you know that OpenCL is very similar), I learnt OpenGL, and now I am starting discovering GLSL..

Given that I read GLSL has some limitations compared to Cuda/OpenCL, but it is faster and has a wider compatibility, is it possible to implement what I need in GLSL? And if yes, does it have any problems/limitations so strong that it might be not worth?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on what do you want to calculate?

Comment: @Trax, I tried to elaborate it, let me know if it is enough clear :)
Regarding the images, unfortunately I dont have an higher resolution copy, I made them bigger by the double..

Comment: If you posted some pseudo code to outline the algorithm you want to implement then it would be easier to comment on whether or not this is possible in GLSL.

Comment: One limitation you sometimes run into when trying to do general purpose calculations in GLSL is that on some platforms you don't have access to floating point textures, sometimes you can only store integer values. (To get the data into your GLSL shader you store vectors or matrices as textures).

Comment: Cannot I just simply access geometry inside VBOs in GLSL shader? Do I have really to store data as texture?

Comment: You should be able to use VBOs however most GPUs have more fragment processors and therefore fragment shaders are typically used for general purpose computing. Here's a good article from GPU Gems http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter31.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an algorithm to work well with [GPGPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_computing_on_graphics_processing_units) (General-Purpose computing on Graphics Processing Units) you need to be able to express what you need to calculate in terms of matrices or vectors so that you get [SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD). Here's agood article from [GPU Gems](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter31.html).

After having a quick look at your description of the calculation it seems to me that you should be able to do this. You transfer input data (like your mirror points) with textures and you transfer your output data with textures as well. However single points or vectors can be sent as a GLSL uniform vector.

However since GLSL isn't intended for GPGPU it does take quite a lot of effort and time. Getting all the texture coordinates right can be very tricky. So if you're in hurry to implement this, GLSL is probably not the way to go.

One limitation you can run into when trying to do general purpose calculations in GLSL is that on some platforms you don't have access to floating point textures, sometimes you can only store integer values. (To get the data into your GLSL shader you store vectors or matrices as textures). Specifically I've run in to this with the iPhone 3GS, don't I know about later versions.